# Open Specific Help Page in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to open a specific help page in Matlab's offline documentation browser programmatically, for example the DAQ Properties.

This would be the page in the online help:
https://de.mathworks.com/help/daq/propertylist.html

I only know how to open specific pages like this:

```
doc('daq/NotifyWhenDataAvailableExceeds')
```

Is there a way to open the Property List directly programmatically in the offline documentation browser?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Matlab Technical Support:

> To view the installed version of the page in the Help browser, run
>   this command:
>
> ```
> web(fullfile(docroot, 'daq/propertylist.html?s_cid=doc_ftr'))
> ```